# Looking for Zoom Navigation Slider feature in Google Visualization Charting Library

Tags: navigation, slider, google-visualization, zooming

I would like to achieve the following chart functionality which is similar to the charts seen in the following link (a line chart with zoom navigation range slider on the bottom / top ) but using GOOGLE VISUALIZATION charting library

HighCharts.js
https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line

amCharts.js
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/line-chart-with-scroll-and-zoom/

It would be nice if I achieve the similar / related  functionality in google visualization api

If not, any related feature would be fine too.

Could someone please assist me on this?

Thank you so much in advance.

Jaffar

Comment: check the [ChartRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter) control...

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat . I will take a look and let you know.